# Django: Return array in subquery

Tags: django, postgresql

I have a model `Application` that has many `Judge` objects assigned to it via ForeignKey. Each `Judge` will grade the `Application`. I want to return a list of Applications in a QuerySet along with an array of each of the score values. Here's how I"m trying to accomplish that:

```
total_scores = Subquery(
    Judge.objects
    .filter(
        application=OuterRef('pk')
    )
    .values_list(
        'total_score',
        flat=True
    )
)

applications = Application.objects \
    .annotate(
        score_array=total_scores
    )
```

But I get this error:

> more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

The `values_list` should return an array of values, so i'm not sure why multiple rows are being returned from my subquery. Any pointers? Thanks.

Comment: But a values_list is still multiple rows.

Comment: That is not the way you are supposed to do that. Yes PgSQL has array support, but it is typically not a good idea to do it that way.

Comment: @DanielRoseman From the documentation, >>> Entry.objects.values_list('id', flat=True).order_by('id')
<QuerySet [1, 2, 3, ...]>. That is a queryset that returns 1 array, which is what i want.

Comment: Can you post the models of the `Judge`, `Application` (and the model in between)? The relevant parts are sufficient.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Can you elaborate? I need a list of applications with an annotation of a list of scores given to each application...

Comment: No, it is a list that represents a queryset of multiple rows.

Comment: @AlxVallejo: see the `array_agg` aggregate function: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-aggregate.html

Comment: @AlxVallejo: and indeed, what you show is *not* an arry, those are *individual* rows. The syntax is due to the fact that you can see a queryset as an enumerable of these rows, and so Django shows it as if it was a list of rows.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem That's promising. Do you know how I would implement the ArrayAgg method in Django? Following https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/_modules/django/contrib/postgres/aggregates/general/, I get `type object 'Aggregate' has no attribute 'ArrayAgg'`. So do i need to create this method?

Comment: @AlxVallejo: probably with a raw SQL query, since the Django ORM only supports a subset of the SQL dialects.

Comment: There's an ArrayAgg function in django.contrib.postgres, see [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/postgres/aggregates/#arrayagg).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First of all, arrays are typically not a well implemented structure in most (all) databases, so I would advice to keep away from it as much as possible. Especially since it structures row-wise data into a single column, which makes it harder to perform `JOIN`s, etc.

But if you really want this, you can use the [**`ArrayAgg`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/postgres/aggregates/#arrayagg) aggregate function. This is however a *PostgreSQL specific function*, thus you lose some freedom to pick another database system.

You can then probably obtain such result with:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.aggregates import ArrayAgg

Application.objects.annotate(
    score_array=ArrayAgg('judge__total_score')
)
```

So this does not require a `SubQuery`.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not quite sure what my other options are to optimally return just the data I need here. I will be performing some calculations across the array sets. I don't need to perform any other joins on the aggregated arrays. I'll be calculating statistics measures on each and then some quartile analysis, etc.

Comment: What if you want not just the `total_score`, but also the `name` of the judge, for example? Is there no way to do this? https://codeshare.io/PdnAKe

Comment: @Audiopolis you can use `ArraySubquery` instead of `ArrayAgg` in your codeshare